# Html5 on windows phone

Tags: css, html, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to html5 on windows phone and now I am having two problems:

1. when I touch the objects appear one mask.
2. when I touch the screen, my application was rolled away.

Situation like the picture that I described, who has experience with this please just help me.
Thanks Everyone!!

[Image: windows phone html5 app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWxGT.png)

Answer (score 0):

The layer is completely normal, its produced by the over event on CSS.